# How to remove Anti-bot Validation in cscart without affecting the site or breaching the security

Tags: security, cs-cart, anti-bot

I want to remove the anti-bot validation from my cscart v4 without it affecting the site. And also I would like to know if the security of the site can be breached without the anti bot validation.

I'd like to take it out from the sign-in pop-up, registeration page etc.

Any takes? please help out

Answer (score 2):

To disable Antibot you should do the following:

1. Go to the Settings->Image verification page
2. Disable all the checkboxes under the "Use for" section.

As for the security: If you disable anti-bot you can get some spam letters - experience will show.